# Python with elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I want to run a painless script to generate new fields for the query results I get from the Elasticsearch client in python, the script is multiline. For some reason whenever I try to run the search method with the script included in the body it gives me a 'search_phase_execution_exception'. Is it because I'm passing a multiline string on the dictionary?

Code sample:

```
{"query":
    "bool": {
        "filter": [ ...]
    }
},
"script_fields": {
    "new_field": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": """ <multilineScriptHere> """
        }
    }

}
```

The script has some ifs and elses in it and also regex matching. I imagine it's a problem with the string, since if I change it to a one line simple script it runs fine and with no problems.